# overload << operator to work with pointer to string

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, find, overloading

I am learning to use the `find` method and from my knowledge it returns an iterator to the found item , this is my sample code which i am trying to find the string "foo"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> foo;

    vector<string>::iterator v1;
    vector<string>::iterator v2;

    v1=foo.begin();
    v2=foo.end();

    foo.push_back("bar");
    foo.push_back("foo");



    std::vector<string>::const_iterator it = find(v1, v2, "foo");

    cout<<*it;

}
```

I am getting the following error when i try to compile the code

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I am unable to cout the deference to the pointer, it seems i must overload the `<<` operator but it is weird that i must overload the `<<` operator to work with string as i can already do

```
string boo = "bar"
cout<<boo;
```

What is happening and how can i solve this problem ??

Comment: That's not a pointer, it's an iterator. And you're using `std::string` without including `<string>`.

Comment: @chris, it should be perfectly fine to use the dereference operator(star) on an iterator. *it should return the string it is pointing to.

Comment: @Uri, I never said it wasn't. All I said was that the OP was mistaken in calling an iterator a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to compile it under GCC, but MSVC rejects it. As chris's comment indicates, adding `#include <string>` solves the problem.

Your program then crashed when running. You assigned to `v1` and `v2` before your assigned the values to the vector, so the result of `it` never points to "foo". Moving the two assignments to below the two `push_back` statements should solve the problem. Still you need to check the return result of `it` as follows:

```
if (it != foo.end()) {
    cout << *it << endl;
} else {
    cout << "*** NOT FOUND" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `#include <string>` and you should be fine.

Also, make sure you compile with C++11 (not the default with some compiler).

Also, to be on the safe side, take `v1` and `v2` *after* you `push_back` the values. `v1` and `v2` could point to obsolete location after vector has changed.

Comment: Not relevant. No C++11 features are used.